# How can I pass an Object from javascript to java with DWR?

Tags: java, spring, struts, dwr

I am able to pass String and int but not Object. Is it possible?

```
 var map = new Object();
    .. Add to object....

         MyManager.setValues(map, {
             callback:function(message){
                 alert(message);
             },
             errorHandler:function(eMessage){
                 alert(eMessage);
             }
         });
```

setValues expects java Object in the java tier

Comment: `Object`? Really? Not some class? You probably need a bean class to use with DWR. Or maybe a Map? What is the Java signature for `MyManager.setValues`?

Comment: @Thilo it used to be Map<String, Object> but i changed it to Object then cast to make things easier

Comment: Not making it easier for DWR...  And even in Java, removing type information seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dwr converters.
Follow this link, this article has described in detail what you need

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/converters/bean.html